# $all-query that takes ordering into account

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in my MongoDB-database:

```
{"stats": [2,5,1]}
{"stats": [1,9,2]}
```

Now I want to find those documents which have a `stats`-array that contains the values `2` and `1` (in that order). So only the first document should be found. A simple `$all`-query would return both documents. Is there a way to do this with MongoDB's query-language?

Or lets assume the following documents:

```
{"stats": [{"val": 2, "position": 0},{"val": 5, "position": 1},{"val": 1, "position": 2}]}
{"stats": [{"val": 1, "position": 0},{"val": 9, "position": 1},{"val": 2, "position": 2}]}
```

Same question :-) Is there a way to query these documents to return only those which have a value 2 followed by a value 1 (take the position-value into account)?

I could probably use a `$where`-query, but the documentation says that this is not the preferred way (and is slow) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$all and $in do not take any ordering into account. Means: not doable with the standard query syntax.